# How to find out the amount of hard drive space consumed by installed programs?

Tags: hard-drive, disk-usage, installed-programs

I was wondering if there is any way to see the total hard drive space used by any  program, after the installation has been completed?

Comment: Marked as duplicate of which question exactly?

Comment: I would disagree the question itself is a duplicate since someone who wants to know the hard drive space usage of installed programs would more directly find this question, rather than the other questions looking for other things like "size of a package while using apt prior to downloading" or "list all installed packages". 

Would there be any suggested changes I can make to this question?

Comment: Indeed. I want to determine the **total size** of all installed package, not list them or print the size of a single package before downloading.

Comment: By the way, I found [my answer](https://github.com/rolfen/tech-journal/blob/master/entries/linux/debian/monitoring_disk_usage.md) - using `wajig`, I do: `wajig sizes |sed -E 's/^\S+\s+(\S+).+/\1/' | sed -E s/,// | awk '{s+=$1} END {print s}'`

Comment: well you could make your question body more consistent with the title. What exactly are asking? Do you want to see a list of installed programs? The space needed by a particular program? Or the total hard drive space used by all installed programs? The latter is what it sounded like to me, from reading the title, but then I read the body of the question and it seems that you are asking for a list. I suggest you clarify either the title or the body of the question to reflect your intent and avoid misunderstandings, please. I would appreciate it!

Comment: @Rolf I have clarified the question. Hopefully that would be enough to not be a duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this graphically in Synaptic. if it is not installed, Install it with the command:

```
sudo apt install synaptic
```

then:

- First ensure that you enabled the `Installed Size` and `Download size`
  columns (or only one if you want that one).
- To do this, go to `Settings>Preferences` and choose `Columns and
  Fonts`, then tick the columns you want to see.
- !Then click "OK".

Now whenever you will search package **It will show Download size and installed size**.

Comment: Thanks. This was actually exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 4):

For a particular package:

```
apt-cache show <packagename> | grep -E '^(.*Size|Version|Package)'
```

Add or remove fields in the grep string as necessary. Since multiple versions may be present, I added the Version and Package fields as well. Note that the `Installed Size` field is an estimated value, in KB, whereas the Size field is for the package file and is in bytes.

Example:

```
apt-cache show blender | grep -E '^(.*Size|Version|Package)'
Package: blender
Version: 2.71~git201406121839.169c95b-0irie1~trusty1
Installed-Size: 140334
Size: 39108640
Package: blender
Installed-Size: 63238
Version: 2.69-4ubuntu2
Size: 18696012
```

To get a list of installed packages, see [How to list all installed packages](https://askubuntu.com/q/17823/158442) Essentially:

```
dpkg --get-selections | grep -v deinstall
```

Comment: Thanks. I noticed that the Installed-size listing gives a slightly different number than what is shown in Synaptic. What accounts for that difference?

Comment: @plu According to the [Debian Policy Manual](http://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-controlfields.html#s-f-Installed-Size): ` Actual installed size may vary based on block size, file system properties, or actions taken by package maintainer scripts.` for example, a package like flash-installer downloads flash in the maintainer scripts. The exact reason would depend on the package. Synaptic probably computes the total size of the all the files in the package.

Answer (score 3):

I am a big fan of [baobab](http://www.marzocca.net/linux/baobab/) to figure out where the big files are hidden.
To install:

`sudo apt-get install baobab`

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here is an answer which doesn't show directly asked packages info, it is covered in other answers in this thread, but though you will probably find helpful to have a list of what takes a lot of space on your file system.

`sudo du / -h|sort -n -r|less`

will show you the biggest files of your `/` at the top of the screen. 
It is generally related to looking for taken space,

Comment: To me, this fails to answer the question as it is not related to *installed programs/packages*. This command will calculate the size of `~`, where most programs are not.

Comment: @JohnWHSmith I though by analogy one can replace `~` with `/` but ok, I changed it.

Comment: Again, this does not answer the question. `du` acts at a lower level : it measures file sizes. It can't tell the size taken by a package, or a set of packages (unless you tell it exactly where each and every file of the package is, which will probably take you some time).

Comment: Generally it is related to the search for taken space.